# Remove trailing comma in CSV file written for a vector using copy and ostream_iterator

Tags: c++, csv, vector, std, ostream

I have the following function, which writes a `vector` to a CSV file:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

bool save_vector(vector<double>* pdata, size_t length,
                 const string& file_path)
{
  ofstream os(file_path.c_str(), ios::binary | ios::out);
  if (!os.is_open())
    {
      cout << "Failure!" << endl;
      return false;
    }
  os.precision(11);
  copy(pdata->begin(), pdata->end(), ostream_iterator<double>(os, ","));
  os.close();
  return true;
}
```

However, the end of the CSV file looks like this:

```
1.2000414752e-08,1.1040914566e-08,1.0158131779e-08,9.3459324063e-09,
```

That is, a trailing comma is written into the file.  This is causing an error when I attempt to load the file using another software program.

What is the easiest, most efficient way to get rid of (ideally, never write) this trailing comma?

Comment: Your problem will soon be solved: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ostream_joiner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you observed, copying via `std::copy` doesn't do the trick, one additional `,` is output. There is a proposal that will probably make it in the future C++17 standard: [`ostream_joiner`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ostream_joiner), which will do exactly what you expect.

However, a quick solution available now is to do it manually.

```
for(auto it = std::begin(*pdata); it != std::end(*pdata); ++it)
{
    if (it != std::begin(*pdata))
        std::cout << ",";
    std::cout << *it;
}
```

Comment: i'm using `-std=c++11` as a compiler option right now.  it looks like that's not gonna work for me (with regard to getting `experimental`).  what should i be using?  or maybe i need to install `experimental`?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be included yet in gcc, I couldn't compile with gcc5.2.

Comment: i've been using `c++` version 4.8.4 and `g++` version 4.8.4 (which may or may not be the same thing) with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'd omit printing the comma by treating the first element special:

```
if (!pdata->empty()) {
    os << pdata->front();
    std::for_each(std::next(pdata->begin()), pdata->end(),
                  [&os](auto&& v){ os << ", " << v; });
}
```

Obviously, this code goes into a function printing a printable range adapter.

Comment: I don't understand exactly how this works. Shouldn't you go up to the `end() - 1` element? But if you treat the last element special then you'd have issues with e.g. `std::forward_list`, which is only ForwardIterable.

Comment: @vsoftco: yes, there was a -1 missing. ... and, yes, it doesn't work with `std::forward_list` which isn't what the question is about (using `-1` actually also doesn't work with `std::list` but that can be fixed using `std::prev()`).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, besides already listed:

```cpp
std::string sep;
for (const auto& x : *pdata) {
    os << x << clusAvg;
    sep = ", ";
}
```

or

```cpp
auto it = pdata->begin();
if (it != pdata->end()) {
    os << *it;
    for(; it != pdata->end(); ++it)
        os << ", " << *it;
}
```

or

```cpp
auto it = pdata->end();
if (it != pdata->begin()) {
    --it;
    std::copy(pdata->begin(), it, ostream_iterator<double>(os, ", "));
    os << *it;
}
```